# Insane SmartGWT + GWT situation... Error on instantiating ListGridRecord?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, instantiation

I am asking this here in the hope that someone has maybe come across this situation too... I have posted this on the SmartGWT forum:

I am having an issue when trying to instantiate a ListGridRecord object on my server side. I am using the ListGrid on the client side, I want to use GWT's RPC to pass back an array of ListGridRecord objects to populate the grid with. I know that SmartGWT is designed to link to a datasource but I want full control over when I populate the grid and this shouldn't be as much of a nightmare as it is to do.

I have searched high and low and cannot find anyone complaining about the same thing. The exception however (listed below) has come up (in my search findings) as a possible memory error - where increasing the memory (-Xmx512m argument) has apparently solved the problem. It did not, however, sort out mine.

If anyone can shed any light on this I would greatly appreciate it!

Here are my details:

Developing using Eclipse Galileo on Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty) and GWT 2.0.3, I built the initial GWT project using the webAppCreator bundled with the GWT 2.0.3 release and imported the project into Eclipse as described on the GWT Getting Started Page (as using the GWT Eclipse plugin caused even more nightmares when trying to connect to a database - this is apparently due to using the Google App Engine and turning it off as all the posts suggested only causes ClassNotFound exceptions).

The line that causes the error is literally:

```
ListGridRecord a = new ListGridRecord();
```

The error I get is the following:

```
00:00:25.916 [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException : Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String za.co.company.product.client.service.EmployeeService.getAllEmployeeAsListGridRecord()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.smartgwt.client.util.LogUtil.setJSNIErrorHandler()V
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:378)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:581)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java :62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488) Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.smartgwt.client.util.LogUtil.setJSNIErrorHandl er()V
at com.smartgwt.client.util.LogUtil.setJSNIErrorHandler(Native Method)
at com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject.<clinit>(JsObject.java:30)
at za.co.company.product.server.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.getAllEmployeeAsListGridRecord(EmployeeServ iceImpl.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java :62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Thanks in advance!

Xandel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer / solution [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?p=25518).

Bottom line is that you cannot instantiate a Record or a ListGridRecord object on the server side because it relates directly to JavaScript and meant for only the client side...

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

In general you can say that everything that belongs to the SmartGWT JAR should never be used on the server.
To avoid misuse you may create three projects and split the classes into 
 1. client side 
 2. service interfaces 
 3. server side

but it's probably not worth the hassle, I guess you know for what to look the next time that happens :-)

Comment: Indeed I will! It was driving me absolutely nuts! :) I am now very careful with where I code what... :P